# slidingdrawer contents overlapped with the view

Tags: android

when i tap the handler the slidingdrawer is brought up but its contents are transparent i can see both the content and the listview.the listview is not hidden.

here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvq"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>


    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lvq"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lvq"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="History" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Just try to set background Color/Image to content part of Sliding drawer. Its transparent by default.

Answer (score 2):

Put your SlidingDrawer below your ListView.

```
android:layout_below="@id/lvq"
```

Comment: sry that i forgot to say ive tried this already.it didnt make any difference.